# How to push 2 div elements together?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 columns of numbers that I want them to appear side by side. It works when I try using `float: left` but I want them to appear in the center. Without the `float` they appear one row then next row downwards.

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#roll, #roll2, #roll3, #roll4 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #0077ee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}

.roll-h {
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shadow {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(40px);
}

.black,
.his-h {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}



.floatleft { 

float: left;

}
```

```html
<div class="floatleft"> 
 
<div class="shadow"></div>
<div class="roll-h">
  <div id="roll3">
    <div class="black">9</div>
    <div class="black">0</div>
    <div class="black">1</div>
    <div class="black">2</div>
    <div class="black">3</div>
    <div class="black">4</div>
    <div class="black">5</div>
    <div class="black">6</div>
    <div class="black">7</div>
    <div class="black">8</div>
    <div class="black">9</div> 
    <div class="black">0</div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="floatleft"> 
 
<div class="shadow"></div>
<div class="roll-h">
  <div id="roll4">
    <div class="black">9</div> 
    <div class="black">0</div>
    <div class="black">1</div>
    <div class="black">2</div>
    <div class="black">3</div>
    <div class="black">4</div>
    <div class="black">5</div>
    <div class="black">6</div>
    <div class="black">7</div>
    <div class="black">8</div>
    <div class="black">9</div> 
    <div class="black">0</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add a parent (container) div around all your html with following styles:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block">
```

see it here:

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#roll, #roll2, #roll3, #roll4 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #0077ee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}

.roll-h {
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shadow {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(40px);
}

.black,
.his-h {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}



.floatleft { 
  float: left;
}

.container {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="floatleft">

    <div class="shadow"></div>

    <div class="roll-h">
      <div id="roll3">
        <div class="black">9</div>
        <div class="black">0</div>
        <div class="black">1</div>
        <div class="black">2</div>
        <div class="black">3</div>
        <div class="black">4</div>
        <div class="black">5</div>
        <div class="black">6</div>
        <div class="black">7</div>
        <div class="black">8</div>
        <div class="black">9</div>
        <div class="black">0</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="floatleft">

    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="roll-h">
      <div id="roll4">
        <div class="black">9</div>
        <div class="black">0</div>
        <div class="black">1</div>
        <div class="black">2</div>
        <div class="black">3</div>
        <div class="black">4</div>
        <div class="black">5</div>
        <div class="black">6</div>
        <div class="black">7</div>
        <div class="black">8</div>
        <div class="black">9</div>
        <div class="black">0</div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can center and keep items side by side using `inline-block` like this

```
.floatleft {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to eliminate the gaps in between?

Comment: couldn't try it, i think you removed the codepen, but i think setting a negative `left-margin` might do it

Comment: i test and see adding `display: inline-block;` to `floatleft` divs does not work. see my answer